# Localizing Exception Messages using Spring

Tags: java, spring

I want to localize the exception messages thrown from POJO classes using Spring. I have a Spring MVC application through which I can add books. If the added book's title is null the implementation class throws an Exception. I want to localize this.

I know I can use the localeResolvers in the JSP pages and I have done that already. Can I leverage this to pick up localized error messages in the POJO? If so how do I inject the locale resolver (Cookie or Session) or locale which was set on the Cookie/Session into the POJO class?

**addBook method throwing exception**

```
    public void addBook(IBook book) throws Exception {
    if (book.getTitle() == null || book.getTitle() == "") {
        throw new Exception("Title is null");
    }
```

I want the `throw new Exception("Title is null")`; to be something like

```
String msg = rBundle.getMessage(propKey)
throw new Exception(msg);
```

where **rBundle** is a bundle object which knows its locale and the properties file from which it should pick the value for propKey

**my controller class method which receives the form submission**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processSubmit(
        @RequestParam("siteLanguage") String siteLanguage,
        @ModelAttribute("book") Book book, BindingResult result,
        SessionStatus status, HttpServletRequest arg0) {
    logger.debug("Adding a Book");
    Locale loc = RequestContextUtils.getLocale(arg0);

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "error.htm";
    } else {
        try {
            Author author = new Author("Gabriel Garcia Marquez");
            book.setAuthor(author);
            library.addBook(book);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "redirect:home.htm";
    }
}
```

Is this possible? Or is it better I control the loading of java ResourceBundle for the respective locale.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you want to localize Exception?: I guess the exceptions are stored in a log file, the administrator should be able to read them, without knowledge of all the languages the users speak.

If you are talking about form validation, then have a look at spring form validation and jsr303 bean validation, both include concepts of localisation. (But both does not work with exceptions.)

Comment: Some of the exception messages are propagated onto the UI, so thats why we need them to be localized.

Comment: In this case, I recommend to use message codes in you Exception. But as fare I know, Exception localization is an architectural decision, so you need to do it in the specified way from beginning of your project. Changing an architectural decision later on, is very expensive in the most cases.