# Java Spring boot Internationalization for Default Spring error messages

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, internationalization

I'm working on internationalization on an existing Spring boot project, I've been having issues trying to figure out if default spring/spring boot errors can be converted automatically.

I have it working for `MethodArgumentNotValidException` spring somehow converts it to the language specified in the request header

```
@ExceptionHandler({MethodArgumentNotValidException.class, BindException.class})
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleBadRequest(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, WebRequest request) {
    Locale locale = request.getLocale();
    ApiResponseEnvelope envelope = new ApiResponseEnvelope(false);
    BindingResult result = ex.getBindingResult();
    List<FieldError> errors = result.getFieldErrors();

    for (FieldError err : errors) {
        ApiError ae = new ApiError(messageSource.getMessage(err, locale), 44);
        envelope.addError(ae);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity(envelope, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "result": null,
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "ne peut pas être nul",
            "code": 44
        },
        {
            "message": "ne peut pas être nul",
            "code": 44
        },
.
.
.
```

But now for other exceptions that go through the `@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)` handler it returns the exception as English. I believe somehow Spring should have a way of returning these generic errors in a localized language.

Below the only way I can seem to convert an exception handled by the `Exception.class` handler is by reading from my messages file. Is there a way to handle these generic errors?

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleExceptions(Exception ex, Locale locale) {
    String errorMessage = attemptToFecthMessageForCode(ex,locale);
    //messageSource.getMessage(ExceptionProperty.UNEXPECTED_ERROR.getValue(), new Object[]{ex}, locale);
    //ex.printStackTrace();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new RestMessage(errorMessage), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}

public String attemptToFecthMessageForCode(Exception ex, Locale locale){
    String msg = ex.getMessage();
    try{
        msg = messageSource.getMessage(ex.getMessage(), ex.getStackTrace(), locale);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return msg;
}
```

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between e.getMessage() and e.getLocalizedMessage()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24988491/5221149)

Comment: See also [Localizing Exception Messages using Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5731397/5221149)